How to get all NFT(NEP-171) owned by specific account in near protocol?
I want to get all NFT account owned.
The way I found is just get account owned token in specific collection.
  const params = {
    request_type: 'call_function',
    method_name: 'nft_tokens_for_owner',
    account_id: CONTRACT_NAME,
    args_base64: encodeArgs({
      account_id: ACCOUNT_NAME,
    }),
   finality: 'final'
  };

How can I get all NFT tokens that specific account owned regardless of collection address.
Or is there any way to get all collection list which the account owned NFT token belong?

On NEAR owner data is stored on the contract (be it FT or NFT) and not the users account (wallet) therefore there is no on-chain solution to this task.
Wallet applications use indexers (listening for events) or/and archival data nodes to keep track on those.
RPCs and Validators generally store up 5 epochs of data so we cant query that trough them.
What you will need to hit an API that provides access to archival data.
https://pikespeak.ai/wallet-explorer/starpause.near/nfts
(change starpause.near with your account)
This functionality is not yet available in the API that pikespeak provides but it is in the works AFAIK. Keep an eye of https://doc.pikespeak.ai/
or check for other providers.

thx for answering! I'll try with that api.
if don't mind, can you recommend any near community to learn more about nft contract code?

https://near.chat  -> Dev Support Channel or Telegram Group @neardev

omg! thx!! i truly be big help to me!

@ms8 Please accept the answer so it might help other people facing the same or similar issue
